# how to provide value to the filereader in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

This is my below function i want to directly provide value to file reader which will read csv file from c:\mp.csv and perform it task.

```
 $("#csv").bind("change", function (event) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function (theFile) {

         try {
             alert(theFile.target.result);

             var input = $.csv.toArrays(theFile.target.result);

         } catch (e) {
             alert("CSV Parse error.");
             return;
         }
         $("#output").pivotUI(input, {
             renderers: $.extend(
             $.pivotUtilities.renderers,
             $.pivotUtilities.gchart_renderers,
             $.pivotUtilities.d3_renderers)
         });
     };
     reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
 });
```

Comment: Javascript can't access files without the user selecting them. This would be a severe security violation, as it would allow a web application to read any of the user's files.

Comment: then what is the alternative for it. if i send file path from 1 page to 2nd page and i want to use that path to read file how can i do that.

Comment: the first page can put the data in `localStorage` and the second page can read that.

Comment: yes my 1st page store the data to my localstorage but how to read that file from my LocalStorage.

Comment: Use `localStorage.getItem` to read it.

Comment: thanks for your help @Barmar. how can i use that in my function i am new to jquery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55693/discussion-between-mayur-and-barmar).